# Rails TimeZone Wrong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, timezone

I have a problem with timezone "Santiago". Chile changed to daylight time (GMT -3) from 1st september.

> > Time.now.in_time_zone("Santiago")
> >     => Tue, 04 Sep 2012 10:57:43 CLT -04:00 <<-- wrong, should be 11:57:43 CLT -03:00

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: I get Tue, 04 Sep 2012 12:24:38 CLST -03:00 . Have you tried updating your tzinfo gem ?

Comment: Thanks Frederick. i had a old tzinfo gem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Timezone data is provided by the tzdata gem. Rails requires a rather up to date version (iirc at least 0.3.31 for Rails 3.2.8), but as time zone definitions are rather short lived, sometimes you need to update them manually. In your case, you need at least 0.3.32 which includes the changes of the Chile DST. At the time of writing of this answer, the current version of tzdata is 0.3.33.

To force a newer version of tzdata, just add this to your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'tzdata', '~> 0.3.33'
```